# Prevent hotkey from being lost after a UAC prompt in Windows

Tags: c#, uac, screenshot, hotkeys

### BACKGROUND

- I wrote an app in C# that registers windows hotkeys (it takes a screenshot when I press PRINTSCREEN)
- My code to register the hotkey, capture screen , etc all works. No issues there.

### THE PROBLEM

- IF my app is running (and successfully has registered the hotkey) and then I do something that causes a UAC prompt - usually this is caused when, for example, I launch some setup program - then the hotkey is lost. Lost = afterwards when I hit printscreen the event never comes back to my app. I have to close the app and restart.

### THE QUESTIONS

- Why is the hotkey lost?
- What can and should I be doing different differently when registering the hotkey?

### NOTES

- I've seen this behavior with other applications that register hotkeys - running the app with the hotkey using admin privileges prevents the hotkey from being lost
- What can and should I be doing different differently when registering the hotkey?
- Avoiding apps like setup.exes that cause the UAC prompt is not a viable solution - the entire purpose of my taking screenshots is to document a setup experience over a number of applications
- I have a workaround in that I can launch the app with admin rights - but I would rather avoid having to do make users do that

### CODE

My code is very similar to this: http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/ea68475b-c33e-4a71-8008-90f63d7e918d.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Given that `Print Screen` already takes a screenshot and puts it on the clipboard, have you considered monitoring the clipboard for changes instead?

Look at the [SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052.aspx) API function. For [example](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx).

Comment: I agree. I’ve made an entire app that's based on clipboard monitoring (though not for images) and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something that may cause an UAC - why not unregister the hotkey first and then register it again afterwards?

Comment: That specific techqinue will work if my app is causing the UAC. My app is not the source of the the UAC prompt - so there is no way for my to unregister the hotkey just before the UAC prompt appears. A user is launching my app and may be taking screenshots of any application - some of them will cause a UAC prompt - it can't predict this programmtically. 

Perhaps a related technique I could try is to detect if a UAC prompt has occured since my app started and then unregister/register the hotkey.

Comment: You should be able to detect a UAC dialog with a CBT-Hook, I guess - if you can't find a more direct way. Another approach could be just to keep registering your hotkey on a timer. Indeed ugly - but if it works...